# Python - In Selenium .text number extract and clickandhold()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I extract the number from a  element? The issue : 20px
I want to extract only the number in INT type.

The second Issue, how can I select a random point/location and select an area inside the element? I dont really know how to use the action.clickandhold() in pixel ...

The website : https://www.pixact.ly/

The code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


PATH = "H:/python/venv/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
action = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("https://www.pixact.ly/")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_id("mobi-close").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("enter").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
canvas = driver.find_element_by_id("canvas")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
pixelwith = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/div/p[1]/span").text
pixelheight = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section[1]/div/div/p[2]/span").text
pwith = str(pixelwith)
phigh = str(pixelheight)
remw = [int(i) for i in pwith.split() if i.isdigit()]
remh = [int(i) for i in phigh.split() if i.isdigit()]

print(*remw)
print(*remh)
#action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(canvas,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close!

To convert a string to an int you just do `int(string)`

There are plenty of ways to remove the `px` part, i just `split` around `px` and took the first item in the returned array - that will get everything to the left of the `px`. A short version looks like this:

```
return = element.text.split('px')[0]
```

Selecting a random point inside an element isn't needed to win the game. When you do a click or similar it picks the centre of the object anyway.
If you really want it to be a random start point you can try `actions.move_to_element_with_offset` with some random numbers, but it's more complication to factor in.
(let me know if you really need this to be a random start point)

Also, a good to know is you don't need to set the implicit wait for each action - you just do it once. `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` configures the driver object to dynamically wait x seconds before throwing an error. Every call that uses `driver` after this has this configured.

This is the combined final code with how i like stuff grouped: (note that i also didn't get the mobi-close object - so re-add that line if you need)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

PATH = "H:/python/venv/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH) 
driver.get("https://www.pixact.ly/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#driver.find_element_by_id("mobi-close").click() # i don't get this
driver.find_element_by_id("enter").click()

#get the elements
width = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Width')]/span").text.split('px')[0]
height = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Height')]/span").text.split('px')[0]
canvas = driver.find_element_by_id("canvas")

#run the actions
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(canvas, width, height).perform()
```

*(I also updated your xpath identifiers to be a bit more logical, hope that's OK.)*

With this, you get the smiling magic unicorn of success:

[image: unicorn of success]

---

[update - even though no one asked]

I enjoyed it enough to figure out how to do the offset. My laptop is old and the resolution isn't great so i couldn't do the final round (the >200px ranges) without causing errors for it going out of screen range

So this is the alternative to start from the top left to give adequate drawing space:

```py
action = ActionChains(driver)
#action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(canvas, width, height).perform() # old line
action.move_to_element_with_offset(canvas, 10, 10).click_and_hold().pause(1).move_by_offset(width,height).release().perform()
```

Stick that in a loop and you're able to score 0 every time:
[image: zero score]

Comment: Thank youu! <3
How can I restart the loop?